Why does the past simple of class 4 irregular verbs (bear, break) resemble that of class 1 verbs (write, ride) (bore, rode etc)?
In 'class 4' irregular verbs like bear and break, in the past simple the vowel o appears, as with 'class 1' irregular verbs like write and ride. Why is this?

bear                                                        bore

break                                                     broke                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

write                                                      wrote

ride                                                         rode



It isn't clear what you're asking. Could you make yourself a bit clearer?

@user405662 I mean Class 1 verbs have long ī which gave long ā in the past that turned into long ō in ME but I do not understand why Class 4 verbs which had short e which gave short æ in the past turned into long ō

It may help to see that the rules help learners group patterns together, but they came after our language worked. So expect a mess and you won't be disappointed.

Wikipedia has a long article on irregular verbs of various types, but on a quick reading I didn’t notice anything on four classes. Please explain the question using examples.

@Xanne https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Gothic_class_4_strong_verbs

@HungarianMan That link doesn't help, because English is not Gothic. English is English (even though might be historically linked to Gothic). I'm not sure why you think write>wrote should exclude the possibility of bear>bore. Please edit the question so it stands on its own without needing to read comments (and without annotations like "Edit" -- simply put all the information into a coherent question).

The terminology doesn't seem to apply in English classification. See here [BYJU] for a decent classification schema (minus any coded group=headings).

@EdwinAshworth That depends whether you're looking for synchronic patterning or diachronic patterning. Here they are listed with the diachronic categories from Proto-Germanic and Proto-Indo-European philology, such as Strong Class 1 vs Strong Class 4, etc.

@tchrist The 'classes' pertaining to the source languages primarily or solely?

@AndrewLeach https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_class_4_strong_verbs
